# Background/after x minutes fetch

Tags: react-native, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I need to make the data I fetch and save in redux to be fetch in the background or on some x minutes.

The application have a database with records that are updated constantly (sometimes 10 up to 1h) and now i have to kill the app so the date to be fetch again.

Everything in my code is basic redux with action and 5 reduces with Fetching API and dispatch the data.

```
export function fetchStatsFromAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getStats())
    fetch(Config.SERVER_URL + '/mob/sport/getPlatfromStats', { //home
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        code: "7",
        sessId: session,
        data: {
            client_id: client,
            u: user
        }
    })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
        let data = res["data"]["response"]["data"];
  dispatch(getStatsSuccess(data))
  })
})
.catch(err => dispatch(getStatsFailure(err)))
}
```

And the other parts is just basic Redux and redux-thunk.

How i can make this fetch to be running every X minutes even when the user opened the app? I tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-fetch but i dont know how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use sockets in the backend so that the server can send an event to your app as and when the data changes and you can listen to it and update your redux state. if you just want to fetch data every x minutes you can make do with a fetch call inside setTimeout.

`

```js
componentDidMount(){
  this.timer=setInterval(()=>this.fetchData(),x*60*1000)
 }
fetchData() {
   //your fetch call
  }
componentWillUnmount(){
 clear(this.timer)
}
```